# What are the units for Dialog MFC Resource Measurements

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog

In this declaration syntax from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381003(v=vs.85).aspx

```
nameID DIALOG x, y, width, height  [optional-statements] {control-statement  . . . }
```

what are the units used for width and height?

I assumed that they were pixels, and so set my window to 640x480. However, I now have a window that is too big for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The units are dialog units as explained in the [DIALOGEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381002(v=vs.85).aspx) resource definition statement. The `DIALOG` is deprecated. Excerpt:

> **x**
>   Location on the screen of the left side of the dialog box, in dialog units.
>
> **y**
>   Location on the screen of the top of the dialog box, in dialog units.

To retrieve the dialog based units use the [GetDialogBaseUnits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645475(v=vs.85).aspx)
function. As per xMRi's suggestion, for a non system font use [this technique](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/125681/how-to-calculate-dialog-base-units-with-non-system-based-font).

Comment: For a non system font (and this is the case for all standard dialogs in modern windows applications) you have to use: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/125681/how-to-calculate-dialog-base-units-with-non-system-based-font

Comment: @xMRi Appreciate it. I have updated the answer as per your input.