# Translation *.rc file affect button size when use JP fonts (MS UI Gothic, 9)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, mfc

Translation *.rc file affects button size when use JP fonts (MS UI Gothic, 9).
Did someone have a similar problem in your application and know idea where the problem might be?

[Button not aligned to icon (button size affected by windows *.rc file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUaUK.png)

Comment: May help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297886/what-are-the-units-for-dialog-mfc-resource-measurements

Comment: Couls you post a picture that show what you want vs. what you get?

Comment: With other languages button size is square and icon bmp is aligned to button edges.

Comment: Dialog units are based on font metrics. It comes to no surprise, that JP font has different metrics than Latin font. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/125681/how-to-calculate-dialog-base-units-with-non-system-based-font